# Error when creating an array: Expression must have constant value

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, opencv3.0

i have work on code for recognition hand gesture using Hu Moment extraction feature, from here [enter link description here](https://github.com/P-bhandari/Opencv-Tutorials/blob/master/Youtube%20CHannel/HandSignsDetection.cpp) but I have a problem for declaring an array

```
int matchTheState(vector<Point> present_hand_state, vector<vector<Point > > MyContours)
{
double array[MyContours.size()];
```

while the contents of the `vector<vector<point>> MyContours` is an image declaration that is used as a comparison value.

the error said:

```
expression must have constant value (cannot call non-constecxpr function...)
function call must have a constant value in a constant expression
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ array bounds must be compile time constants. `MyContours.size()` is not a compile time constant. Just use a vector instead.

```
vector<double> array(MyContours.size());
```

Comment: yes it work to eliminate the errors. but when i start to debug, a notification appears that Debug Assertion Failed! Vector subscript out of range.

Comment: @RirisEkaS OK, well that just means you have a bug in your code. Since I can't see the code I can't say what the bug is. If your can't figure it out make a new question and include the code that crashes.

Comment: may I send you the whole code? so you can tell me what the bug is. would be so happy if you want to help me sir:(

Comment: Sir, this is my new question about debug problems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61474002/error-when-debug-debug-assertion-failed-vector-subscript-out-of-range