# Error when debug: Debug Assertion Failed: Vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, vector, opencv3.0

I have work on code for recognition hand gesture using Hu Moment extraction feature, but when i start to debug, a notification appears that Debug Assertion Failed! Vector subscript out of range. someone told me that I you have a bug in my code, but I still can't figured it out. Please help me. Here's the crashed code

```
//function hand image declare and preprocessing image
//function contour detection
//function bounding box
int main()
{

VideoCapture cap(0); //capture the video from web cam

if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
{
    cout << "Cannot open the web cam" << endl;

}
vector<vector<Point> > MyContours = getTestCases();
string array[] = {"V","W","Y"};
while (1)
{
    Mat imgOriginal;

    bool bSuccess = cap.read(imgOriginal); // read a new frame from video
    if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
    {
        cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
        break;
    }
    Mat send;
    imgOriginal.copyTo(send);
    vector<Point> present_hand_state = detectHand(send);

    double area = contourArea(present_hand_state, false);
    cout << area << endl;
    int a = matchTheState(present_hand_state, MyContours);

    if (a != 100 & area > 500)
        imshow("ImgOriginal", imgOriginal);

    waitKey(23);
}
}

int matchTheState(vector<Point> present_hand_state, vector<vector<Point > > MyContours)
{
vector<double> array(MyContours.size());
int answer = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < MyContours.size(); i++)
{
    double match_value = cv::matchShapes(MyContours[i], present_hand_state, CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I2, 0);
    array[i] = match_value;
    if (array[answer] > array[i])
        answer = i;
}
if (array[answer] < 0.9)
    return answer;
else
    return 100;
}
```

while the contents of the `vector<vector<point>> MyContours` is an image declaration that is used as a comparison value.

```
vector<Mat> testCases;
vector<vector<Point> > MyContours;
Mat test = imread("D:\KULIAH\TA\database\F1\frame_v_thres.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
testCases.push_back(test);//1
test = imread("D:\KULIAH\TA\database\F1\frame_w_thres.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
testCases.push_back(test);//2
test = imread("D:\KULIAH\TA\database\F1\frame_y_thres", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
testCases.push_back(test);//3
```

Comment: *someone told me that I you have a bug in my code, but I still can't figured it out* -- That error message "Vector subscript out of range" is a Visual C++ runtime error.  You get a big message box stating to "Retry to Debug".  Did you do that?  If you did, you would see exactly where the error occurred by looking at the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that's leaping out at me is that if `MyContours.size()` equals zero then `if (array[answer] < 0.9)` would be a subscript out of range error. You could test this by changing the code to

```
if (!array.empty() && array[answer] < 0.9)
```

But it's only a theory, there's too many unknowns here to be sure.